# URI Online Judge 1021 - Wrong answer 100% (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, uri

Estou tentando resolver o problema 1021 do URI em JS, porém, recebo 100% de erro.

> Leia um valor de ponto flutuante com duas casas decimais. Este valor
>   representa um valor monetário. A seguir, calcule o menor número de
>   notas e moedas possíveis no qual o valor pode ser decomposto. As notas
>   consideradas são de 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2. As moedas possíveis são de
>   1, 0.50, 0.25, 0.10, 0.05 e 0.01. A seguir mostre a relação de notas
>   necessárias.
>
> Entrada O arquivo de entrada contém um valor de ponto flutuante N (0 ≤
>   N ≤ 1000000.00).
>
> Saída Imprima a quantidade mínima de notas e moedas necessárias para
>   trocar o valor inicial, conforme exemplo fornecido.
>
> Obs: Utilize ponto (.) para separar a parte decimal.

Meu código:

```
var input = require('fs').readFileSync('/dev/stdin', 'utf8');
var lines = input.split('\n');

const valor = lines.shift();

const notas = [100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2];
const moedas = [1.0, 0.5, 0.25, 0.1, 0.05, 0.01];

let n = parseFloat(valor);

console.log('NOTAS:');

notas.forEach(nota => {
  console.log(`${parseInt(n / nota)} nota(s) de R$ ${nota.toFixed(2)}`);
  n %= nota;
});

console.log('MOEDAS:');

moedas.forEach(moeda => {
  console.log(`${parseInt(n / moeda)} moeda(s) de R$ ${moeda.toFixed(2)}`);
  n %= moeda;
});
```

O que se espera:

```
Exemplo de Entrada

576.73

Exemplo de Saída

NOTAS:
5 nota(s) de R$ 100.00
1 nota(s) de R$ 50.00
1 nota(s) de R$ 20.00
0 nota(s) de R$ 10.00
1 nota(s) de R$ 5.00
0 nota(s) de R$ 2.00
MOEDAS:
1 moeda(s) de R$ 1.00
1 moeda(s) de R$ 0.50
0 moeda(s) de R$ 0.25
2 moeda(s) de R$ 0.10
0 moeda(s) de R$ 0.05
3 moeda(s) de R$ 0.01
```

O que estou fazendo de errado?

[image: Print do console]

**RESOLVIDO:**

Verifiquei no fórum do URI que algumas pessoas relataram problemas com outras linguagens também. Consegui resolver acrescentando 0.00001 nas divisões das moedas para arredondar:

```
n = (n % moeda) + 0.00001;
```

Comment: Você só está fazendo pro primeiro elemento do array, não? Fora isso, qual o exemplo de output que o programa quer?

Comment: Mostre um print do seu output

Comment: Editei o post com essas informações.

Comment: Você testou o programa localmente?

Answer (score -1):

Provavelmente pelo enunciado, ele só quer valores inteiros. Do jeito que você tá fazendo, por exemplo: você recebe o `valor = 50`, e ao dividir por todas notas, você divide por 100 também, o que dá um output de `0.5 nota(s) de R$ 100`, o certo seria não usar essa nota.

Edit: retirar também o `parseInt()`, já que você não está convertendo uma string para inteiro. Se quiser arredondar, use os metodos do Math.

Documentação MDN sobre `parseInt()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: E o `parseInt` no resultado da divisão?

Comment: Exatamente! Usei o parseInt no console.log.

Comment: @Woss não tinha visto, adicionei na resposta.

Comment: Mas não é esse o problema. A própria documentação que você citou diz que se o parâmetro não for uma *string* ele é convertido para tal antes de retornar o inteiro, desta forma é possível obter a parte inteira de um float com esta função.

Comment: Se quiser testar, tire as duas primeiras linhas de código e faça `const valor = 576.73`. A saída é exatamente a esperada no exercício.

Comment: Entendi, mas nesse caso, o próprio corretor do exercício pode identificar isso e zerar a resposta não? Porque você tá usando um parseInt() aonde não é necessário.

Comment: Exatamente, @Woss! Coloquei um print exatamente do que você disse no enunciado.

Comment: @leofalmeida Não entendo em que ponto você quer chegar. Testa no console isso aqui: 

console.log(10/3)
console.log(parseInt(10/3))

O resultado do segundo console é exatamente o esperado.

Comment: @AnaCarolinaHernandes Eu entendi essa parte, estou falando o seguinte, o resultado tá certo? Sim, está. Mas está implementado da maneira certa? Quem corrige isso? É uma correção automática ou um ser humano que está falando que está errado? Porque alguém pode ver seu código, ver usando um `parseInt()` em algo que não é uma string, mesmo o javascript convertendo automaticamente, não é maneira "certa" de resolver o problema, se você está lidando com números, o mais "correto" seria usar o `Math`. E mesmo uma correção automática pode verificar tais coisas.